# cannot import name Shrinkage

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I'm running a python script which uses Shrinkage class from pyRiemann package.
Even though that I've installed this package, I got this error:

```
from pyriemann.estimation import Shrinkage
ImportError: cannot import name Shrinkage
```

I'm using:
pyriemann==0.2.4
Python 2.7.13 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)

any idea what this problem is?

Comment: It looks like it should be available [from 0.2.4](https://github.com/alexandrebarachant/pyRiemann/commit/f92766642a595950efa474deb3d55a8895ac047f#diff-202a83d02f1b113a6b35d57f5013e974) so the question is: are you sure you're using the right version? do you know that it's installed properly ? are you using virtualenv ? which OS are you using ? and etc...

Comment: Looking at the latest commit on Github seems to indicate otherwise, it should be added in 0.2.5: https://github.com/alexandrebarachant/pyRiemann/blob/159b7548e1cc9b784b15214bc42fd358a1e84108/pyriemann/estimation.py#L498 And the code is clearly not in module downloaded by pip when installing pyriemann==0.2.4 (see lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyriemann/estimation.py
) Maybe there was some miscommunication within the pyRiemann team regarding these release notes?

Comment: The commit @alfasin linked was after the 0.2.4 release. August 2016 compared to June.

Comment: @alfasin: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS, the version of pyRiemann is 0.2.4.
However, I'm not sure if it is installed properly. I didn't get any error while installing, but the fact that it's getting me error tells that sth is wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `Shrinkage` is not in pyRiemann 0.2.4.

The code is on Github, so the development version could be installed with:

```sh
pip uninstall -y pyriemann
pip install git+https://github.com/alexandrebarachant/pyRiemann
```

If you work with other people and put the git link in a `requirements.txt` file, consider locking yourself to a specific commit, e.g. the current latest one. And then remember to change it to `pyriemann==0.2.5` once that is released.

Comment: But the Github code is 0.2.4 too! I didn't find version 0.2.5 on the repo. I installed from github, as you suggested, but the version is still 0.2.4.

I could see the class 'Shrinkage' in the source files of pyRiemann, but for some reasons, it didn't work when calling it.

Comment: The Github code is a development branch. So it's technically not a version at all. It is version 0.2.5-devel -- or whatever number they chose to for the next release. It is still 0.2.4 in pip's eyes, which is why `pip uninstall pyriemann` is needed beforehand.

Comment: You did call `pip install git+https://github.com/alexandrebarachant/pyRiemann` but weren't able to import `Shrinkage`? Or the import worked but then there are problems with using the class?

Comment: First, it didn't work for some reasons. I tried the same thing again, and this time it worked! thanks.

Comment: Pleas upvote as well if you are happy with the answer :)